# Fetch mongodb collection data to csv in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

Please find the document structure of my collection:

```
{
"_id": "9759572745-Sing",
 "details": {
"Gender": "M",
"PreTrainingStatus": "Fresher",
"Religion": "Hindu",
"attendanceInPercentage": "",
"batchHolders": {
    "AssessmentDate": "Thu Jul 16 2015",
    "CourseFee": "7500",
    "isEditable": false
},
"batchID": "282726",
"eid": "",
"whereDidYouHearAboutStar": "---Select---",
"skillInstructorOrTrainerName": "282726",
"specificGovtInstitutetieups": "---Select---",
"isSelected": false,
"isEditable": false
},
"addedOnMs": 1439455766000,
"submittedOnMs": 1439454813000,
"latitude": "27.409566879272",
"longitude": "77.69295501709",
"locationName": "Uttar Pradesh 281006,null"
}
```

I want to print all the nested properties to be displayed in a column. But I am not able to do so, can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set nested option value to true

```
Specify fields that you want from JSON. 
For nested document you can specify like this batchHolders.AssessmentDate (it will give you "Thu Jul 16 2015") and so on for others also.
```